# Get values from object using Backbonejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

i want to get value from this API `http://demo82.com/lois/api/get_page/?id=6` using Backbone js. i tried but i don't know how can we get values from object in backbone.

here is my Backbone code

```
Page = Backbone.Model.extend({
initialize: function() {
        this.on('all', function() { console.log(this.get('page')); });
    },
    url: "http://demo82.com/lois/api/get_page/?id=6",
    defaults: {
        "id":null,
        "title":"",
        "content":""
    }
});


 var page = new Page();
 console.log(page.fetch({}));
```

i am new and try to learn backbonejs please explain what is the better way ? please give me ans using `jsfiddle.net`.
thanks

Comment: we prefer putting code inline to SO over putting it on something like jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Is `id` always going to be 6? In your code, your model is always getting the 6th thing. If you want a custom url with a get parameter, override `url` as a function:

```
 url: function() {
      id = this.get("id");
      return "loispage/api/get_page/?id=" + id
 }
```

Better yet, if you have control over the server side and can do something a little more RESTful with a page entity -- simply set urlRoot

```
 urlRoot: "loispage/api/page/"
```

and fetch will automatically do an HTTP get from

```
 "http://.../loispage/api/page/<id>
```

Comment: have a look at:
http://demo82.com/lois/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/img.jpg
i just want to get desired values title,content, etc ..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a context problem (`this` doesn't refer to the model in `on`'s callback).  You can fix this by specifying the context:

```
this.on('all', 
    function() { console.log(this.get('pagel')); },
    this
);
```

**Edit**

There's also a cross-domain issue.  You'll need to use a JSONP request for this by overriding *sync* and *parse*.  ([I adapted the following code from this example.](https://gist.github.com/1245613))

```
var Page= Backbone.Model.extend({

// override backbone synch to force a jsonp call
sync: function(method, model, options) {
    // Default JSON-request options.
    var params = _.extend({
      type:         'GET',
      dataType:     'jsonp',
      url:            model.url(),
      processData:  false
    }, options);

    // Make the request.
    return $.ajax(params);
},

parse: function(response) {
    // parse can be invoked for fetch and save, in case of save it can be undefined so check before using 
    if (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        // here you write code to parse the model data returned and return it as a js object 
        // of attributeName: attributeValue
        return { status: response.status };    // just an example
    }
},
```

[Here's a JSFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Tpe4s/12/)

Comment: result is demo82.com/lois/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/img.jpg but i just want to get desired values title,content, etc .. .

Comment: @Furqan you just have to parse as needed.  Use eg `return { title: response.title, ... }`

Comment: i am working on same domain. this is not cross domain issue.
do you think $.ajax() is better way ? please have a look 
http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/introduction-to-backbone-js-part-5-ajax-video-tutorial/

Comment: @Furqan no, if you're on the same domain, then it's much easier/better to use `.fetch()`.

Comment: http://furqankhanzada.com/backbonejs/ here you can see and object on browser console. 
and code is here http://furqankhanzada.com/backbonejs/wp-content/themes/loispage/js/main.js
question is that how can i render desired data from Object.